# Sort data in inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join

```
select Distinct 
    _Ad.ad_id, _Ad.Ad_Name, 
    ID.Image_Path, VM.year, 
    VD.Vehicle_Transformation, VD.Vehicle_Fuel_Type, VD.Vehicle_Mileage
from 
    _Ad 
order by 
    Ad_Date_Created
inner join 
    _Image_Details ID on ID.ad_id = _Ad.ad_id 
inner join 
    _Vehicle_Model VM on VM.vehicle_model_id = _AD.vehicle_model_id 
inner join 
    _Vehicle_Details VD on _ad.ad_id = VD.ad_id;
```

I keep getting an error that multi part data can not be bound. Please help to correct query

Comment: no, it's giving you an error because your sql is wrong. the syntax is `select ... from ... join ... where `. you have order/join reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Distinct 
    _Ad.ad_id, _Ad.Ad_Name, 
    ID.Image_Path, VM.year, 
    VD.Vehicle_Transformation, VD.Vehicle_Fuel_Type, VD.Vehicle_Mileage
from 
    _Ad 
inner join 
    _Image_Details ID on ID.ad_id = _Ad.ad_id 
inner join 
    _Vehicle_Model VM on VM.vehicle_model_id = _AD.vehicle_model_id 
inner join 
    _Vehicle_Details VD on _ad.ad_id = VD.ad_id;
order by 
    Ad_Date_Created
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your SQL statement is wrong. An ORDER BY clause should come after the JOIN's